# On initialization of non-aggregate structures

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following code:

```
template<size_t head,size_t ... Dims> struct make_vec {
      typedef typename make_vec<Dims...>::type type[head];
};

template<size_t head> struct make_vec<head> {typedef float type[head];};

template<size_t ... Dims>
struct vec {
    typename make_vec<Dims...>::type _data;
};
```

Since the class `vec` is an aggregate, I can use brace-enclosed-initializer lists to initialize `vec`.

```
vec<3,3> foo = {{
    {1,2,3},
    {4,5,6},
    {7,8,9}
}};
```

If I add a constructor to my vec class (for example to allow the use of expression-template, which is my ultimate goal), this syntax is no longer allowed, since `vec` would not be an aggregate anymore.

In this case, the logic thing to do would be to use `std::initializer_list`; however, when I compile a code which uses this construct, I get a long assembly code even with optimization  enabled (I use `std::uninitialized_copy` to copy from the initializer_list to my vec class data member).

I had no luck in using variadic templates to achieve the same result.
What is the best way (i.e. good runtime performance and clear syntax) to initialize user-defined fixed-size multi array types?

Comment: I forgot but another possibility is to make the types of your expression templates have an implicit conversion operator. No need for a constructor then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a constructor taking

```
typename make_vec<Dims...>::type const&
```

which will allow user code to use the same style of initialization as if it were an aggregate. If you're using GCC this might need a recent version, like GCC 4.7.

I have no idea about the generated code however.

Comment: This seems to work. I use std::memcpy to initialize the _data member, and GCC 4.7 is able to optimize that.